# Subscript out of range error after importing data from another workbook to userform

Tags: excel, vba, lost-focus

i have a userform which can open another workbook to import some data. This second workbook is closed after that with

```
OpenBook.Close False
```

Then i save this data to the first workbook with a button in the userform.
Everything works perfect.

However if i open this second workbook in excel before the data is saved, then by clicking the save button i get an **"Subscript out of range"** error. (when setting ranges in the first workbook, ie.

```
Set list1 = Worksheets("Special name").Range("Special column")
```

It seems that the focus is on the second workbook, and there is no such worksheet.

How can i bring back this focus to the first workbook?

I've tried

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

with no luck.

Thanks!

edit:
I use this code to open the second workbook:

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set tsh = OpenBook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Please add the code you use for opening. That is where it all starts

Comment: Don't use Activate. Tell VBA which workbook you want to use, eg `Set list1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Special name").Range("Special column")`.

Comment: #Sam: i put the code in the post.
#FunThomas: yes, that works, but i have a lot of those, it would be better with a single code than updating every line with worksheets.

Comment: You should make it a habit to specify every time exactly what you want to access. Don't go down the road to use `Activate` all the time. Makes the code slow and unreliable. Why? Imagine you use Activate, then Call a Subroutine. After the routine returns: Can you be sure that the Workbook/Worksheet is still active? Maybe the subroutine uses also Activate?

Comment: to expand on @FunThomas if you use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Special name")` at the top of your code you can then use `Set list1 = ws.Range("Special column")` then if you need to change worksheet you can either use ws2 or just change the assignment of ws this makes the code much more robust and quicker to ran and update

Comment: ok to your actual question it's hard to fully tell what's happening but opening a new workbook will change the focus, `ThisWorkbook.Activate` should change the focus so it shouldn't be that but not fully clear.  if you step through the code ([link](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/8020/debugger-locals-window) or more detailed ([link](https://madschedules.com/microsoft-project-vba-locals-window/)) you should be able to see what workbook is in focus, though as mentioned this is not a recommended why to mange the issue

Comment: I wonder, after you put `ThisWorkbook.Activate` ---> this will activate the workbook where the sub is (whatever sheet which active). How about if you try to select any cell after `ThisWorkbook.Activate`, something like `range("Z100").select`. Will it select Z100 on the whatever active sheet ? If it does select Z100, then I think your next code `Set list1 = Worksheets("Special name").Range("Special column")` should work. Or you may try to test it first with `Sheets("Special name").activate` (assuming that at the time you activate the ThisWorkbook, the active sheet is not sheets "Special name").